# MVC-like Autogenerated Pages for Webforms

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, model-view-controller, webforms

I noticed that MVC lets you pass in LINQ to SQL objects to its views and it will autogenerate Create, Update and View Pages based on the LINQtoSQL object.

**Is there anything for webforms that lets you do this kind of thing?  (In would be nice if it had validators...)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28y3u2uc45kakrr555dijiwvf2%29%29/DynamicData/) and Scott's Blog [Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/14/new-asp-net-dynamic-data-support.aspx)